# c# how can i check if img file exist in div class

Tags: c#, testing

The problem is that I can not check if there is a file on the page.
There is a code in which this image is present:

```
<div class="specials-block">

<a href="/ru/actions/443">
<div class="specials-block-item icons-guide ico1" data-amount="5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="">
</div>
</a>
<div class="specials-block-item">
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEsA......8X2F0UZvgYHv0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
</div>
</div>
```

And the code in which this image is missing:

```
<div class="specials-block">

<a href="/ru/actions/443">
<div class="specials-block-item icons-guide ico1" data-amount="5" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="">
</div>
</a>
<div class="specials-block-item">

</div>
</div>
```

In order to check whether this image is present, I do a check:

> ```
> var intelAtom = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/img[@src='------------------------------']"));
>    if (intelAtom.Displayed)
>    {
>        MessageBox.Show("All is OK");
>    }
>    else
>    {
>        MessageBox.Show("WTF O_o , displayed enother Icon");         
>    }
> ```

but I need to check both the presence of the image and if the img dislayed that the desired image is displayed.
Somthing like this:

> ```
> if (driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/img")).Displayed)
> {
>     var intelAtom = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/img[@src='------------------------------']"));
>     if (intelAtom.Displayed)
>     {
>           MessageBox.Show("All is OK");
>     }
>     else
>     {
>           MessageBox.Show("WTF O_o , displayed enother Icon");
>     }
>  }
>  else
>  {
>      MessageBox.Show("WTF O_o , Icon Intel Pentium is't displayed");
>  }
> ```

But if I start second query, it was failed, because it didn't find img file

> driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/img"))

.

Perhaps someone knows how to build the right query in order to determine whether the image was displayed on the page and the correct image was displayed

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually asking... also, the image here is _not_ a file; it's a raw base64 data block.

Comment: perhaps I was not rightly questioned,
 I ask, can I check,
 Is there a element <img src = "value"> in <div class = "specials-block-item">

Comment: Who is in charge of putting the image into the html code? Your code?

Comment: You might want to use more attribute selectors (ids or at least css-classes) if available.

Comment: @Fildor code written by programmers, the image is pulled automatically from the CRM-system. If the image is placed in the CRM, a random image name is automatically generated and the image is displayed on the page.

Comment: Ok, and now you need to verify that because ....? I think if you really need to do this, "the programmers" should give you some help in adding ids as Manfred already suggested. Without it, it's going to be messy.

Comment: @Fildor I want to cover several images in one test, and if I do not have one image then the test will fall and the rest will not be checked. So I wanted to do the same with the text
<div class = "specials-block-item">
<img src = "name of img">
</ div>

 var img1 = driver.FindElement (By.XPath ("// div [@ class = 'specials-block-item']"));
                    if (img1.Text.Equals ("name of img"))
{}
else
{}
 I understand that the "text" does not apply here. Can I use something instead of "text"? Or how it is possible to find out there is img in
<div class = "specials-block-item">